# Vue.js $scopedSlots don't work for Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, clusterize

I'm working in a Vue component that I'll publish when it's finished that wraps [Clusterize.js](https://clusterize.js.org/) (there is a vue-clusterize component but it only works for v1.x). What I want to achieve is to render a huge list of items pretty fast using Vue. I actually need it for a table. I tried with [vue-virtual-scroll](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller) but it [doesn't support tables](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller/issues/8) and the performance is not that good. So I wanted to try with Clusterize.js.

Because I want this component to be highly configurable I decided that you will be able to provide a scoped slot for each row of the items list where you will receive the item. The problem is when I try to assign the scoped slot from the clusterize componets to each row before mounting the component it doesn't work.

Here you have some snippets of my code (it is just a mvp)

**clusterize.vue**

Template

```
<div class="clusterize">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Headers</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<div
  ref="scroll"
  class="clusterize-scroll">
  <table>
    <tbody
      ref="content"
      class="clusterize-content">
      <tr class="clusterize-no-data">
        <td>Loading...</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Script

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Clusterize from 'clusterize.js';

export default {
  name: 'Clusterize',
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      clusterize: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    rows() {
      return this.items.map(item => '<tr><slot :item="1"/></tr>');
    },
  },
  watch: {
    rows() {
      this.clusterize.update(this.rows);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    const scrollElem = this.$refs.scroll;
    const contentElem = this.$refs.content;

    this.clusterize = new Clusterize({
      rows: this.rows,
      scrollElem,
      contentElem,
    });

    this.clusterize.html = (template) => {
      contentElem.innerHTML = template;
      const instance = new Vue({ el: contentElem });

      instance.$slots = this.$slots;
      instance.$scopedSlots = this.$scopedSlots;
      instance.$mount();

      console.log(instance.$scopedSlots); // empty
      console.log(instance.$slots) // not empty
    };
  },
};
```

**component.vue**

```
<clusterize :items="test">
  <template slot-scope="props">
    item
  </template>
</clusterize>
```

The thing is that if it don't use a scoped slot it works perfectly but I really need to use them otherwise the component doesn't have any sense.

I'll appreciate any help or advice.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproduction ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue should be caused by mount different Vue instance to same `el` multiple times (please look into the second demo, **you shouldn't mount multiple instances to same element**, [the following instances will not mount since the element is already “blocked” by first instance](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/create-multiple-vue-instance-with-same-el/40523/3?u=lovemai)).

**My solution**: create Vue instance (doesn't bind to `el`) in the air then take `vm.$el` as the output.

**Please look into below simple demo,**

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('clusterize', {
  template: `<div class="clusterize">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Headers</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<div
  ref="scroll"
  class="clusterize-scroll">
  <table>
    <tbody
      ref="content"
      id="clusterize-id"
      class="clusterize-content">
      <tr class="clusterize-no-data">
        <td>Loading...</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div></div>`,
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      clusterize: null,
      clusterVueInstance: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    rows() {
      return this.items.map(item => {
       return '<tr><td><span>' +item+'</span><slot :item="1"/></td></tr>'
      });
    },
  },
  watch: {
    rows() {
      this.clusterize.update(this.rows);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    const scrollElem = this.$refs.scroll;
    const contentElem = this.$refs.content;

    this.clusterize = new Clusterize({
      rows: this.rows,
      scrollElem,
      contentElem,
    });
  
    this.clusterize.html = (template) => {
      this.clusterize.content_elem.innerHTML = template;
      if(this.clusterVueInstance) {
    this.clusterVueInstance.$destroy()
        this.clusterVueInstance = null
      }
      
      this.clusterVueInstance = new Vue({  template: '<tbody>'+template+'</tbody>' })
      //or use Vue.extend()
      this.clusterVueInstance.$slots = this.$slots
      this.clusterVueInstance.$scopedSlots = this.$scopedSlots
      this.clusterVueInstance.$mount()
      this.clusterize.content_elem.innerHTML = this.clusterVueInstance.$el.innerHTML
      //console.log(this.clusterVueInstance.$scopedSlots); // empty
      //console.log(this.clusterVueInstance.$slots) // not empty*/
    };
  }
})

app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      test: ['Puss In Boots', 'test 1', 'test2'],
      index: 0
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
   //this.test = ['Puss In Boots', 'test 1', 'test2']
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function () {
      this.test.push(`test ` + this.index++)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/clusterize.js/0.18.0/clusterize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/clusterize.js/0.18.0/clusterize.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addItem()">
  Add Item
  </button>
  <clusterize :items="test">
  <template slot-scope="props">
    item: {{props.item}}
  </template>
  </clusterize>
</div>
```

**Please look into below demo:** created multiple Vue instance to same `el`, but Vue always uses first instance to render (I can't find any useful statement at Vue Guide, probably from the source codes from Vue Github we can find out the logic. If someone knows, please feel free to edit my answer or add a comment).

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
    test: 'test 1'
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log('app1', this.test)
  }
})

app2 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
    test: 'test 2'
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log('app2', this.test)
  }
})
//app1.$data.test = 3
//app1.$mount() //manual mount
app2.$data.test = 4
app2.$mount() //manual mount
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/clusterize.js/0.18.0/clusterize.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <a>{{test}}</a>
</div>
```